# Responsive web design with mobile detection interspersed for greater control

Tags: python, web-applications, responsive-design, mobile-website, progressive-enhancement

I have just finished building my first website with a mobile-first responsive design process in mind. The site looks and works great on mobile devices, but the desktop experience is quite lacking. There's no good way I can improve the desktop experience without compromising the mobile experience, and even then there are just some things I can't do using a pure client side approach.

I don't want to have to manage two separate websites (mobile, desktop). What I want to do is have mobile detection server side to have more control of when I load/display more data, etc.

I want to do something akin to:

```
// in view
...
if not request.mobile: 
    related_posts = post.get_related_posts()
...

// in template
...
{% if not request.mobile and related_posts %} 
    {{ related_post_stream(related_posts) }} 
{% endif %}
...
```

Surprisingly, I don't see much online discussion about doing things this way. Most articles I've read either recommend pure (mobile-first) responsive design or a separate mobile website, although this seems like a decent idea. Is there a downside to doing this?

Comment: Are you using media queries in your site currently?

Comment: Yes. The site is responsive from mobile to desktop, the desktop "experience" is lacking however.

Comment: I've found what I was looking for. It's called RESS - Responsive Web Design + Server Side Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django, there is [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) module which allows you to check the mobile usage in the template like this:

```
{% if flavour != "mobile" %}Desktop version{% endif %}
```

If you are not using Django, you can still analyze the source of that module and implement something similar for your website.